# How to avoid two different threads read the same rows from DB (Hibernate and Oracle 10g)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, transactions, locking

Let's suppose I got two different threads, T1 and T2, accessing concurrently the same database and fetching data from the same table.

Now on thread startup I need to fetch data from the table and store the rows into a collection, that I will then use to perform some work elsewhere. I don't want the two threads to be able to process the same data, because it will result in duplicated (and long) work. To be more concrete, this is an enterprise application that needs to load some records at startup and store it in a collection to do some extra work. The problem is that in a clustered environment, this can cause two different instances to load the same data and so the work could be duplicated. So I want the rows to be loaded only once by a single instance.

How can I avoid that scenario?

I'm currently using Hibernate and Oracle 10g. These are my solutions up to now:

- Lock the row programmatically. The first one that reads it sets some "locked" column to true, but deadlock is very likely to occur if the first thread dies without setting the row as "processed".
- Using Pessimistic Locking. I tried with LockMode.UPGRADE but that doesn't seem to help, as I'm still able to read the data from both thread at the same time.

> ```
> public List<MyObject> getAllNtfFromDb() {
>       Session session = HibernateUtil.getOraclesessionfactory().openSession();
>       Query q = session.createQuery(
>               "from MyObject n where n.state = 'NEW'");
>     List<MyObject> list = (List<MyObject>) q.list();
>       for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
>           session.lock(list.get(i), LockMode.UPGRADE);
> return list;
> }
> ```

Any other hints? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use a select for update statement?

Comment: Can you please provide the Hibernate imports used for this line: `Session session = HibernateUtil.getOraclesessionfactory().openSession();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` at query time:

```
Query q = session
    .createQuery("from MyObject n where n.state = 'NEW'")
    .setLockOptions(new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE));
List<MyObject> list = (List<MyObject>) q.list();
```

Locking the parent objects is sufficient. Deadlocks won't necessarily occur. You might get a lock acquisition failure if the thread holding the lock doesn't release it prior to another thread from timing out waiting.

Since you are using Oracle, this is how [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/innodb-locking-reads.html) works:

> SELECT ... FOR UPDATE locks the rows and any associated index
> entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows.
> Other transactions are blocked from updating those rows, from doing
> SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, or from reading the data in certain
> transaction isolation levels. Consistent reads ignore any locks set on
> the records that exist in the read view. (Old versions of a record
> cannot be locked; they are reconstructed by applying undo logs on an
> in-memory copy of the record.)

So if T1 acquired an exclusive lock on some rows, T2 won't be able to read those records until T1 commits or roll-backs. If T2 used a [READ_UNCOMMITTED](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-jan/o65asktom-082389.html) isolation level, then T2 won't ever block on lock records, as it simply uses undo logs to reconstruct data as if it were when the query began. As opposed to the SQL standard, the Oracle READ_UNCOMMITTED will:

> To provide a consistent, or correct, answer, Oracle Database will
> create a copy of the block containing this row as it existed when the
> query began ... Effectively, Oracle Database takes a detour around the
> modified data—it reads around it, reconstructing it from the undo
> (also known as a rollback ) segment. A consistent and correct answer
> comes back without waiting for the transaction to commit.

Comment: Ok thanks, that does work but only if the two threads are trying to read the same data very close in time. If T1 reads the data and after 1 minute T2 reads the same data (which T1 is very likely to be still processing), then T2 is able to see the rows.

I want to lock the row until they are updated (e.g. the state column set to "OK", or "PROCESSED"). 

Also, does updating one entity automatically release the row? And if the session is closed or the thread crashes are the rows released after some timeout? 

Thank you very much.

Comment: It probably depends on the underlying database exclusive lock support.